# cannot convert from 'System.IO.Stream' to 'SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.DecoderOptions'

Tags: azure-functions, asp.net-core-mvc, nuget, azure-blob-storage

I am using SixLabors package to resize an image in Azure Blob Storage, it showing an error while taking parameters saying cannot convert from 'System.IO.Stream' to 'SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.DecoderOptions'.

This is a the code snippet of Visual Studio 2022
[Code snippet showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mR4Af.png)

i am following a course on udemy, in which this error didn't appear.

Answer (score 2):

The NuGet Package Version 3.0.0 of SixLoader.ImageSharp is giving this error. I Downgraded the package version and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

In ImageSharp 3.0.0, they removed **ImageFormat** out params and rather return it with Metadata.
This is the PR: https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/pull/2317

This is the release notes: https://sixlabors.com/posts/announcing-imagesharp-300/
Detailed release notes: https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/releases/tag/v3.0.0

This is the new usage:

```
IImageFormat format = image.Metadata.DecodedImageFormat;
```

"image" is your **SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image image** variable, obviously.